# Creating a table with column headers not having vertical lines between them

Tags: tables

I need to create a table where all the cells have vertical spacing between them except the column headers. It is like [image]

Please help me out with this. I have multiple tables like this one in my thesis doc. Other questions on similar grounds on StackExchange have vertical lines between the columns consistently and not like what I have here

Comment: Well, do you want to omit the vertical lines generally? Your question is unclear, but there is definitely something wrong in your table code ..

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I just want to omit the vertical lines between the column headers except column no 7 , 8 and 9. The above image is just an example of how I want my table to be.

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & ` etc. then. This commands `LaTeX` to group some columns (here only 1) and use a centered column format without `|...|`) -- it will drop the vertical lines. Use it for the first six columns.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer... Allow me to try this out and I will be back if it doesn't work

Comment: But if you want to produce a professional-looking table, don't use vertical lines at all. Read the `booktabs` documentation on this.

Comment: @cfr: Well spoken ;-) The thunderbolts of egreg will soon come ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Alright thanks for the information.. I will get that clarified and then post here accordingly... Even i feel that this is a little weird.. I l definitely get this checked

Comment: But could you please give me an example as to how can i use this multicolumn command. What will \multicolumn{1}{c}{1} do?

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{A}` will put a centred A in the cell with no vertical lines. So if you've defined the `tabular`, say, to use `|l|c|r|`, it will override the column settings for this cell in this particular row.

Comment: But what about the column heading 7 in the above image @cfr.... It has the right vertical line but not the left one

Comment: @ShraySharan: The image shows, that the first 6 columns have no `|` at all, the 7th column just only a right one. As I said: Use `\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & ... & \multicolumn{1}{c}{6}` for the first six columns

Comment: You can adjust it as you want `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Z}` or `\multicolumn{1}{|l}{First}` or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this example work for you?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a&b&c&d\\\hline
1&2&3&4\\
5&6&7&8\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

vs.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c}{a}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{b}&
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{c}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{d}\\\hline
1&2&3&4\\
5&6&7&8\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

These fragments yield the following tables:

[image: tabular environment multicolumn example]

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this example and I got an idea... My problem is solved... Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Just to show the application of `\multicolumn`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{c|}*{3}{l|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 \tabularnewline
\hline
Vector Indicator &  & & & & & & & \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note**

I don't recommend this table layout at all!

Comment: Vertical rules and `booktabs`?!

Comment: @cfr: Don't ask :-P As I said, I would not use it ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I understand that and will get it clarified before using it. But I got the application ... Thank you so much

Comment: @cfr: Stickler to the rules ...